# How to find all the textbox genrated after, "New" clicked in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, detailsview

I am trying to develop a dynamic GUI for Oracle which would allow the user to select a table dynamically and to perform operations like insert,update and delete. I am planning on using the `DetailsView` control, but the problem is I need to get the values inserted inside the text boxes. I am trying to use the `FindControl` method at `mode_changed` and at `item_inserting`. but it is not working. Please could somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would suggest you use Formview to replace your detailsview, you will have more control on GUI

In the inserting event, you can get the value from form collection -- Request.Form

Answer (score 0):

The sample from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcommand.aspx

The "Add" command on that page should be similar to your "New" I presume.

**To Add:**

Oracle connection with ASP.NET.

Sample from Oracle's site:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/11gr2_db_prod/appdev/dotnet/aspprovider/aspprovider_otn.htm